# XercesDOMParser memory leak in parse function

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, xerces-c

I have a memory leak using `XercesDomParser` with following code sample:

```
//setup parser
auto dom_parser_ = std::make_unique<xercesc::XercesDOMParser>();
dom_parser_->setErrorHandler(error_handler_.get());
dom_parser_->setValidationScheme(xercesc::XercesDOMParser::Val_Always);
dom_parser_->setDoNamespaces(true);
dom_parser_->setDoSchema(true);
dom_parser_->setValidationSchemaFullChecking(true);

//use parser multiple times with different xml param 
xercesc::MemBufInputSource xml_buffer((const XMLByte *)xml,
                                       xml.size(), "dummy");

dom_parser_->parse(xml_buffer);
```

I was able to find out that function `XercesDOMParser::parse` leaks memory.

Should I call some function explicitly after each parse call to prevent memory leaks?

Comment: I don't suppose [this is related to your question](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xerces-c-users/200907.mbox/%3C9B5859DE1377F64794DCB6C5483C058E0731F0AA1D@WW001E1ERLMM01.ww001.siemens.net%3E) ? (It was the #1 hit from Google for "XercesDOMParser parse memory leak"; just curious).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I should call release on dom document after each parse call:

```
dom_parser_->parse(xml_buffer);
dom_parser_->getDocument()->release();
```